# Some residue memory never released with ARC?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I have done my best to make sure that views are released when they are no longer needed and when pushing the app and then looking at the *Debug Memory Graph* I see that no objects are present that shouldn't be there. However when I look at the memory graph I can see that although the graph does sometimes bump back down, it still slowly trends upwards. An example is attached.

I am new to building large projects in iOS and am mostly asking is this normal? Is it simply impossible to free **all used memory** with ARC? Or is there still more debugging to be done here?

*(app starts at ~15MB, ends up at 20.1MB)*

[image: memory chart, starts at 15mb and climbs to 20.1mb in small increments with some bumps going downwards]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting at 15 megabytes and levelling off at 20 megabytes is *great*. This app is tiny, and its memory usage levels off quickly. Problems arise when memory usage keeps rising forever, typically on the level of *giga* bytes, i.e. many orders of magnitude bigger! So, don't worry, be happy.